# Lenovo Z50 Laptop - Caps Lock and Num Lock indicator lights won’t turn off

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a Lenovo Z50 laptop where the caps and num lock key lights are always lit. The functionality of the keys is unaffected but would like to know if this is a symptom of something worse and if it’s possible to get the key lights working properly again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First step: identify whether it's a hardware or software issue. Are the lights ever out while the laptop is powered on, like when you first turn on the power and before it starts to boot?

- If they are never off, it would point to a hardware or firmware issue.

  In that case, try plugging in an external keyboard that has status lights. If those work properly, it's likely a defect in the internal keyboard, or possibly a bad keyboard ribbon cable connection.  If the external keyboard does work correctly, or behaves differently, it isn't a 100% reliable indicator that the problem is with the internal keyboard because it will be connecting through a different kind of interface, which may not be active immediately upon power-on.  So additional diagnostics might be needed to confirm.

  However, if the external keyboard has the same problem, that would point to a firmware or hardware issue in the laptop.
- If the lights come on during boot and then stay on, that would point to a software issue.

If you update the question with this additional detail, we'll know what underlying problem to focus on.